# Php foreach give 2 users random value

Tags: php, sql, database, foreach, phpmyadmin

I got this:

```
foreach($users as $user) {

        $newcw = mt_rand(1, 52);
        $set = array('val' => $newcw,
}
```

this basically runs through the user database and give each user a random value between 1 and 52.

How is it possible to give every 2 users one value?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$oldcw = NULL;

foreach($users as $user) {
    if($oldcw){
        $newcw = $oldcw;
        $oldcw = NULL;
    }else{
        $newcw = mt_rand(1, 52);
        $oldcw = $newcw;
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$index = $value = 0;
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($index % 2 == 0)
        $newcw = $value = mt_rand(1, 52);
    else
        $newcw = $value
    // Do something with $newcw
    $index++;
}
```

It generates a new random number every other time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks I will test it out, but why did you do this $index = $value = 0?

Comment: couldn*t you do just $index = 0 or $value = 0?

Comment: Yeah, you could set the variables to 0 on two different lines. That's just my personal preference. When I'm setting more than one variable to an identical initial value, it makes the code look a bit cleaner.